# Android UnixTime incorrect parsing

Tags: java, android

I already read a lot of topics here in StackOverflow and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong (not using integer and multiplying by 1000).

This is my method:

```
public long toUnixTime() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);
    Long aux = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    Long aux2 = 1000L;
    return aux / aux2;
}
```

Values I'm using for tests:

- **Day:** 04
- **Month:** 03 (0-based, so April)
- **Year:** 2016
- **Hour:** 21
- **Minute:** 00
- **Returned value:** 1462406419 (Thu, 05 May 2016 00:00:19 GMT)
- **Expected value:** 1459803600 (Mon, 04 Apr 2016 21:00:00 GMT)

It's driving me crazy

---

### Solution

```
public long toUnixTime() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(year, month-1, day, hour, minute, 0);
    cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return cal.getTimeInMillis() / 1000;
}
```

month-1 = 0-based, so if it's January, I should use 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `Calendar.getInstance();` will return a Calendar instance with its time zone set to the default time zone, which is most probably *not* GMT.

With `cal.set(year, month, day, hour, minute);`, you leave the Calendar's second and millisecond fields untouched (they retain their current value), so if you run your test at x:y:19 o'clock (with x and y being arbitrary values), the calendar's time will still be 21:00:19 after you have set the hour field to 21 and the minute field to 0.

Comment: What can I use instead of Calendar?

Comment: You don't have to use anything else, but to get your expected behaviour, you have to set the calendar's time zone to GMT and the second and millisecond fields to zero.

Comment: Just setting seconds and cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); worked. Thanks!